# Java/C How to modify zip file header?

Tags: java, android, c, zip, gzip

Is there a way i could edit the Zip file header and modify its values ? I have a .zip file with 5 files inside already . I want to edit the header and modify the content .

I am trying to modify the extra field at the end (please ref the zip struture from wiki),

[image]

I am okay with modifying a zip file in any language !Any help is appreciated .

Comment: @rana Where you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify zip file headers with java.util.zip package. But if you know the zip header structure you can use java.io.RandomAccessFile move to the required field and use an appropiriate method (eg writeInt or writeShort) to change its value.

Comment: i edited my question for clarity . please let me know if you can throw any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You will need to roll your own code for this, but it should be relatively straightforward.  Since it sounds like need to insert extra data in the headers, you cannot simply write into the existing zip file as suggested in another answer.  Read the zip file and write a new one.

Start by finding and reading the central directory (the end directory points to it).  Then use that to know where the local and central headers are in the zip file.  You need to do that since some zip files cannot be simply read sequentially without decompressing the data.  For this application, there is no point in wasting time decompressing data.

Then read the zip file sequentially using the locations of the local headers from the central directory, copying the contents to the new zip file, but inserting extra fields by changing the length in extra field length and inserting the extra data.  Keep track of the new offsets of the local headers.  When you get to the central directory, you will need to update the offsets to the local headers, as well as insert the extra data again there.  Finally you will need to update the offset to the central directory in the end directory.

Use the [zip file specification from PKWare](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: It requires some care.  See the link added to the answer.